# react-native reazy unable to resolve module

Tags: react-native

I am trying to test out the `reazy react-native framework`, I can't get the sample app up and running.

when I run the `react-native run-ios` command i am getting the following error:

> unable to resolve module react/lib/reactComponentwithPureRenderMixing
>   node_modules/react-native-router-flux/node_modules/react-addons-pure-render-mixin/index.js
>   Module does not exist in the module map

I have removed my modules and reinstalled them.  the module folder is there for `react-native-router-flux`

nothing in the JS console

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Please install router flux using below and refresh

```
npm install --save react-native-router-flux
```

Hope! this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command and it will be solved-

```
yarn add react-addons-pure-render-mixin
```

this is manual step to add this module.